# Prevent grep results opening in NerdTree window

Tags: search, vim, grep, nerdtree

I've just started using [EasyGrep](https://github.com/vim-scripts/EasyGrep) . Often my NERDTree window is in focus when I am doing a search and the first search result loads in this window.

Is there a way to force EasyGrep to open the first result in the main buffers window?

Thanks!

Comment: Vim has [no notion of project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) so I doubt there is much of a way to avoid this behavior without changing your workflow or submitting an issue to EasyGrep.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I added in my `.vimrc`:

```
function! SearchOutsideOfNerdtree()
  if &filetype == 'nerdtree'
    :wincmd l
  endif
  :execute input("", ":Grep\<Space>")
endfunction

function! ReplaceOutsideOfNerdtree()
  if &filetype == 'nerdtree'
    :wincmd l
  endif
  :execute input("", ":Replace\<Space>")
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>f :call SearchOutsideOfNerdtree()<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>g :call ReplaceOutsideOfNerdtree()<CR>
```

Basically I created a function that checks if the current filetype is `nerdtree` and I move to the right buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I added in my .vimrc and it works:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,g  :<C-u>wincmd w<CR>:Unite grep:. -buffer-name=search-buffer<CR>
```